# Paypal CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile causing a timeout

Tags: php, curl, timeout, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to complete a transaction on paypal sandbox and my request always return timeout error.

I've look everywhere for this problem that seems to be pretty recurrent but no solutions seems to work for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried?  What errors you're getting etc. there could be a million reasons why your code isn't working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I've found solutions to my problem.

as pointed out by ppmtscory on the php-Paypal-SKD github forum, you shoud not use credit card number 4111111111111111 because it as been overused and it is flagged as so in the system and cause this type of behavior.

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/519

> @artisangang I will be closing this issue as it doesn't have to do with the SDK itself. This is due to the specific testing card number being overused in the system causing a timeout. @pp-randy has already filed the internal ticket to do a DB update to try and correct this for the sandbox environment but it's not something that will likely get very high priority. If you need test credit cards, please visit this page and utilize Step 4.